# new Uint32Array(buff, start_pos, arr_len) returning unexpected results with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraybuffer

I've been trying to read large binary files that are gzipped from a URL with a node.js program.  To simplify the problem, I'm trying to read two unsigned ints from the start of the stream.

It appears that given a large buffer, the following code (incorrectly) returns the same array for a1 and a2 in Node.js, but (correctly) will not return the same array when run from within Chrome against the same URL when called using an XMLHttpRequest:

```
var bufferPos = 0;
var a1 = new Uint32Array(bData, bufferPos, 1);
bufferPos += 4;
var a2 = new Uint32Array(bData, bufferPos, 1);
```

Regardless of the content in data, a1 and a2 always appear to be identically long arrays the size of the whole buffer, so I've had to try this which has better results but I then need to convert from an array of values to a Uint32:

```
var bufferPos = 0;
var a1 = new Uint32Array(bData.slice(bufferPos, (bufferPos+=4)));
var a2 = new Uint32Array(bData.slice(bufferPos, (bufferPos+=4)));
```

This code is in a callback and the code that builds content and passes the data to bData is in a https.get call that contains this:

```
//In https.get()
tBuffer = null;
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
resp.pipe(gunzip);
gunzip.on('data', (data) => {
if (tBuffer === null){
    tBuffer = data;
} else {
    tBuffer = Buffer.concat([tBuffer, data]);
}).on('end', () => {
    //callback code in here
    callback(tBuffer);
});
```

Am I handling the response data somehow incorrectly in Node.js that is different from what I would expect in the Chrome XMLHTTPRequest response?  The call to gzip was also a pain... am I missing some step there?

Should I not be trying to parse the response content as a buffer in a callback for some reason?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Normally multiple questions in one SO question are frowned upon :)

Comment: Thanks Patrick... Understood on the multiple questions, in this case, I'm trying to see if they ultimately boil down to the difference (that I don't understand) between new Uint32Array in Chrome vs. node.

Comment: thats why I gave a +1 to a well formulated question and left the reminder for your future ones ;) No experience with node.js and small with js so wont bother to solve it.

Comment: Apparently, this issue is due to some incompatibilities in node.js behavior from ECMAScript 2015.

From the docs: _The Buffer object's memory is interpreted as an array of distinct elements, and not as a byte array of the target type. That is, new Uint32Array(Buffer.from([1, 2, 3, 4])) creates a 4-element Uint32Array with elements [1, 2, 3, 4], not a Uint32Array with a single element [0x1020304] or [0x4030201]._